# Lost session after redirect virtual TPV (bank payment)

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout, session-management

I redirect logged users from my site to a bank payment system. After the user has completed the payment, he is redirected from the bank site to my site, however, in many cases, the session is lost. Any idea?

Here is the logg code:

Connect

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("user", false);
Session["id"] = 1;
```

Disconnect

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Clear();
Session.Timeout = 1;
Session.RemoveAll();
Session.Abandon();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your setup maybe the session is stored on www.yourdomain or yourdomain. For example, if user is logged on from yourdomain and then redirected back to www.yourdomain maybe the session is not there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please how could I know it?

Comment: I suggest confirming first that this is the problem by peforming same steps from both www. and without www. Need to clear cookies etc first.

Comment: Here is the solution:

<system.webServer>
<rule name="Enforce WWW" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>